# How to change name, domain of site in Django

Tags: django

I am able to change the name of the domain and site in the administration panel (http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin). However, when I try to make changes directly to the database in the table `django_site`, it is not reflected in the administration panel (nor is it reflected in the URL of links sent in activation emails).

Why is this change not working directly in the database, and how can I change the site/domain other than in the administration panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/#caching-the-current-site-object), Django caches the site upon the first request. Therefore you need to call `Site.objects.clear_cache()`:

> As the current site is stored in the
>   database, each call to
>   Site.objects.get_current() could
>   result in a database query. But Django
>   is a little cleverer than that: on the
>   first request, the current site is
>   cached, and any subsequent call
>   returns the cached data instead of
>   hitting the database.
>
> If for any reason you want to force a
>   database query, you can tell Django to
>   clear the cache using
>   Site.objects.clear_cache()